# Wiki Platform for .NET

Tags: .net, wiki

Looking for a good choice of .NET-based Wiki Platform.  Doesn't need to be Open Source, but the cheaper the better.

Comment: See [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177293/what-is-the-best-aspnet-wiki-out-there) for relevant information.

Comment: In you question you want "easily skinnable, has an API (auto upload initial wiki content) and scalable" that he might not want...

Answer (score 4):

[Screwturn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.com)
Probably the best in terms of extensibility **and** ease of use/installation.

I have been able to code plug-ins that are immensely helpful and powerful.  This is the main wiki for our development team.

Comment: I use screwturn for some projects and i like it. In my opinion the best .Net wiki engine.

Comment: Screwturn no longer exists, and stopped being developed at the start of 2012 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177293/what-is-the-best-aspnet-wiki-out-there)

Answer (score 2):

[Linked Note](http://www.heartland-it.com/LinkedNotes/ProductInfo.aspx)

[SharpForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpForge)  is an asp.net 2.0(c#) project management application, released under the new BSD license. Each project has its own wiki. Rather than using a special syntax the wiki uses standard HTML. Content is versioned in the version control system.

[FlexWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlexWiki)  is written in C#, uses the .NET framework, and stores data in files or Microsoft SQL Server. FlexWiki is an open source wiki software, released under the CPL (binaries and source code available for download).

[Perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(software)) is written in C#, uses the .NET framework, and stores data in XML files. Binary and Source Code are available for download.

[SharpForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpForge)  is an asp.net 2.0(c#) project management application, released under the new BSD license. Each project has its own wiki. Rather than using a special syntax the wiki uses standard HTML. Content is versioned in the version control system.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I've just released a self made....
http://codebrewery.blogspot.com/2011/02/iknow-release-10.html

It's small, very small but I created it mainly for intranet knowledge-database scenarios..

Answer (score 0):

The demise of ScrewTurn Wiki left a bit of a vacuum in the .net wiki department, but it needed to either die or be re-written.

My modern as of 2023 solution for an opensource, aspnet 7, MVC, SQL Server backend wiki would be [TightWiki](https://tightwiki.com/) (which can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/NTDLS/TightWiki)).